# Start a persisted workflow at any resumption point

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to determine if I'm able to use Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 to handle a process that we have.  We have a process that is a very good candidate for a workflow.  However, I need to be able to persist and possibly resume at a different point than where it was persisted at.  For example, a user will be answering a series of questions.  The questions will be numbered and separated into sections (i.e. 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc.).  If the user decides to quit before the entire section of questions have been answered, I need to persist the workflow.  When the user starts the questions again, I need to start them at the beginning of the section that they last worked on.  Say they answered up to question 8 in the 2nd section of questions (#'s 6-10).  I need to have the user start the workflow at question 6 instead of 8 (where they left off).  Each question would be an activity.  Is this something that is possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't resume from a different point than you saved the workflow state. However you are not required to save the state after every activity. So you can only save the state when it suits you and abort any changes in memory you want to revert.